# Use materialize to show simple_form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, materialize

I would like know as i can to utilize the materialize errors on simple_form.

My form is:

```
  <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
    <%= f.email_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "validate" %>
  </div>
```

I want that in addition to showing red the form it also shows an error message.

Comment: What is materialize errors?

Comment: For example, in validating an e-mail form if the user does not type a valid e-mail, a wrong and low form appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show errors you can add this after you initialise the form.

```ruby
<%= simple_form_for yourObject do |f| %>

<% if f.object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize( f.object.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this field_group from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple form you need to use `f.input`, for example:

```
<%= f.input :email %>
```

This will give you an input and any errors after the form has been submitted to the server.

You will need a validation in the model to actually generate errors which the form will display. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :email, presence: true
end
```